# How can I optimize a somewhat complex binary algorithm in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, binary, bit-manipulation

I am trying to iterate over a large chunk of data and organize the values properly. Context: data is a large set of integers that were interpreted from raw bye data. The integers are actually densely packed data and on top of that the bytes are in a "little endian" order. So, in order to get proper values I have found that I need to read in 3 values, extract each nibble, then reorder them all into the proper orientation.

So, finally to my question. How can I speed up this process or optimize, as right now it takes over a minute to get through all of the data from a single file and I could potentially have thousands of files.

```
for i in range(0, len(data), 3):
            j = struct.pack("=I", data[i])
            p = struct.pack("=I", data[i + 1])
            q = struct.pack("=I", data[i + 2])
            nibble0 = j[1] >> 4
            nibble1 = j[1] & 15
            nibble2 = j[0] >> 4
            nibble3 = j[0] & 15
            nibble4 = j[3] >> 4
            nibble5 = j[3] & 15
            nibble6 = j[2] >> 4
            nibble7 = j[2] & 15
            nibble8 = p[1] >> 4
            nibble9 = p[1] & 15
            nibble10 = p[0] >> 4
            nibble11 = p[0] & 15
            nibble12 = p[3] >> 4
            nibble13 = p[3] & 15
            nibble14 = p[2] >> 4
            nibble15 = p[2] & 15
            nibble16 = q[1] >> 4
            nibble17 = q[1] & 15
            nibble18 = q[0] >> 4
            nibble19 = q[0] & 15
            nibble20 = q[3] >> 4
            nibble21 = q[3] & 15
            nibble22 = q[2] >> 4
            nibble23 = q[2] & 15

k.append((nibble0 << 12) | (nibble1 << 8) | (nibble2 << 4) | 0)

k.append((nibble3 << 12) | (nibble4 << 8) | (nibble5 << 4) | 0)

k.append((nibble6 << 12) | (nibble7 << 8) | (nibble8 << 4) | 0)

k.append((nibble9 << 12) | (nibble10 << 8) | (nibble11 << 4) | 0)

k.append((nibble12 << 12) | (nibble13 << 8) | (nibble14 << 4) | 0)

k.append((nibble15 << 12) | (nibble16 << 8) | (nibble17 << 4) | 0)

k.append((nibble18 << 12) | (nibble19 << 8) | (nibble20 << 4) | 0)

k.append((nibble21 << 12) | (nibble22 << 8) | (nibble23 << 4) | 0)
```

I am looking to do this without using Anaconda or Pypy or any of the pre-built python packages.

Comment: accordigng to your code nibble is reasigned on each iteration, it's not clear what's going on

Comment: is the k.append outside of the loop? cProfile will tell you what is slow, if the appends are part of it, that's a likely contributor if you files are a bit bigger, you could to a temp_list of the comparisons you have and append that once with k += tmp_list

Comment: lookup table/dict? - 12 bits or even 16 not unreasonable

Comment: Sorry, The k.appends are within the loop. I thought I fixed the formatting. I'm new to asking questions here.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you need nibbles only for debug purposes and you can exclude some operations:

```
        nibble0 = j[1] >> 4
        nibble1 = j[1] & 15
        nibble2 = j[0] >> 4
        k.append((nibble0 << 12) | (nibble1 << 8) | (nibble2 << 4) | 0)

    is equivalent to 

        k.append((j[1] << 8) | (j[0] % F0))

   and 
       nibble3 = j[0] & 15
       nibble4 = j[3] >> 4
       nibble5 = j[3] & 15
       k.append((nibble3 << 12) | (nibble4 << 8) | (nibble5 << 4) | 0)   

  is equivalent to 

       k.append((j[0] << 12) | (j[3] << 4))

  (if k gets 16-bit values, otherwise clear MSB bits of j[0])
```